# How does coreos.autologin work?

Tags: autologin, coreos

I wonder how the internals look like that enable CoreOS to auto-login. Does it bypass user-verification? Is this is standard Linux kernel feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It passes the `autologin` parameter to agetty as seen here:

https://github.com/coreos/init/blob/master/systemd/system-generators/coreos-autologin-generator

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I ask the follow up question: How does `agetty --autologin core` work? Maybe I should rephrase the question to explicitly focus on what makes an auto login not require passwords, rather than the coreos specifics.